# Failed to codesign error when running flutter app on iOS simulator in Android studio

Tags: flutter, xcode, android-studio, ios-simulator

I am trying to run a flutter project in android studio, it works with an android emulator. However, it throws an error when I try to run it on the iOS simulator (iPhone 14 pro max in this case).

```
Error (Xcode): Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign (a file path) with identity -.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

I am struggling to figure out what this error means. I have found some solutions talking about certificates in keychain access, but haven't found a solution that works for me. When I run `flutter doctor -v` there are no issues found.

I am using android studio, so I'm not sure if that is part of the issue? I have xcode downloaded but haven't used it yet, some direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you